# Duo3d driver on Jetson TK1

Tags: ros, jetson-tk1

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody.

I have looked really long for a solution but i cant figure out what the problem is.

I am trying to install the ros driver package for the duo3d camera http://wiki.ros.org/duo3d-ros-driver on the Jetson tk1 board.
But every time i try the catkin_make command i will get an error output with:

```
...catkin_ws/src/duo3d_driver/lib/libDUO.so: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [...catkin_ws/devel/lib/duo3d_driver/duo3d_driver] Error 1
make[1]: *** [duo3d_driver/CMakeFiles/duo3d_driver.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j1 -l1" failed
```

Maybe some of you could help me with this problem :-)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258779/duo3d-driver-on-jetson-tk1/) by [moody](https://answers.ros.org/users/23922/moody/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2017-04-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok.
I Figured it out myself:

the Problem was due to the wrong SDK in the devel folder of my workspace. For some reason the Driver had downlaoded the SDK automatically for the amd64. So the solution was to replace the wrong SDK by the one needed by armhf.

---

Originally posted by [moody](https://answers.ros.org/users/23922/moody/) with karma: 31 on 2017-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Flacedoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/30330/flacedoo/) on 2017-07-13**:
Could you please specify what you've done exactly? I am encountering the same problem, but on an ODROID XU4.

**Comment by [moody](https://answers.ros.org/users/23922/moody/) on 2017-08-02**:
Sry for the really late reply: hope you figured it out yourself by now.
Else:
Downloaded the correct SDK from their website and replaced the one in my devel folder with the one for armhf.